# Refreshing value at a list view when activity is re-opened back from another activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I need your help to solve the following concern I have related to an activity.

An activity has a list view showing JSON objects. When the users taps on a row, another activity opens showing more details about the selected object. On this second activity, the user may click on a button to up vote the object. The amount of votes is then increased by one. Then, if the user goes back to the previous activity, the amount of given votes showed is not updated, but should be updated taking into account the vote given by the user.

At the first activity (list view) the number of votes field is given from a previous activity through an intent:

FIRST ACTIVITY CODE (LIST):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Empresas_ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Empresas_ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView valoracionEmpresa;
        TextView nombreEmpresa;
        TextView direccionEmpresa;
        ImageView strImagen;
        TextView descripcionEmpresa;
        TextView telefonoEmpresa;
        TextView facebookEmpresa;
        TextView emailEmpresa;
        TextView textoOferta;
        TextView horarioEmpresa;
        TextView latitudEmpresa;
        TextView longitudEmpresa;
        TextView idEmpresa;


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empresas_listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        valoracionEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        nombreEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        direccionEmpresa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        strImagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        valoracionEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.VALORACIONEMPRESA));
        nombreEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.NOMBREEMPRESA));
        direccionEmpresa.setText(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.DIRECCIONEMPRESA));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.STRIMAGEN), strImagen);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Empresas_SingleItemView.class);

                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("valoracionEmpresa", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.VALORACIONEMPRESA));

                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("nombreEmpresa", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.NOMBREEMPRESA));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("direccionEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.DIRECCIONEMPRESA));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("strImagen", resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.STRIMAGEN));

                intent.putExtra("descripcionEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.DESCRIPCIONEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("telefonoEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.TELEFONOEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("facebookEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.FACEBOOKEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("emailEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.EMAILEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("textoOferta",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.TEXTOOFERTA));
                intent.putExtra("horarioEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.HORARIOEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("latitudEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.LATITUDEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("longitudEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.LONGITUDEMPRESA));
                intent.putExtra("idEmpresa",resultp.get(Empresas_MainActivity.IDEMPRESA));




                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

SECOND ACTIVITY CODE (DETAIL)

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Empresas_SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String valoracionEmpresa;
    String nombreEmpresa;
    String direccionEmpresa;
    String descripcionEmpresa;
    String telefonoEmpresa;
    String facebookEmpresa;
    String emailEmpresa;
    String textoOferta;
    String horarioEmpresa;
    String latitudEmpresa;
    String longitudEmpresa; 
    String imagenstrImagen;
    String idEmpresa;
    String position;
    private ProgressBar pb;
     URL aURL;
        /* Will be filled and displayed later. */
        String aString = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.empresas_singleitemview);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        valoracionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("valoracionEmpresa");


        // Get the result of country
        nombreEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("nombreEmpresa");


        // Get the result of population
        direccionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("direccionEmpresa");

        descripcionEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("descripcionEmpresa");
        telefonoEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("telefonoEmpresa");
        facebookEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("facebookEmpresa");
        emailEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("emailEmpresa");
        textoOferta = i.getStringExtra("textoOferta");
        horarioEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("horarioEmpresa");
        latitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("latitudEmpresa");
        longitudEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("longitudEmpresa");
        idEmpresa = i.getStringExtra("idEmpresa");

        // Get the result of flag
        imagenstrImagen = i.getStringExtra("strImagen");


        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
        TextView txtnombreempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa);
        TextView txtdireccionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccionEmpresa);
        TextView txtdescripcionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descripcionEmpresa);
        TextView txtofertaempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoOferta);
        TextView txthorarioempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.horarioEmpresa);


        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imagenEmpresa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.strImagen);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtvaloracionempresa.setText(valoracionEmpresa);
        txtnombreempresa.setText(nombreEmpresa);
        txtdireccionempresa.setText(direccionEmpresa);
        txtdescripcionempresa.setText(descripcionEmpresa);
        txtofertaempresa.setText(textoOferta);
        txthorarioempresa.setText(horarioEmpresa);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagenstrImagen, imagenEmpresa);
    }

    public void openFacebook(View view) 
    {
        String url = "http://es-es.facebook.com/pages/"+facebookEmpresa;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);


    }
    public void openEmail(View view) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{emailEmpresa});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email desde Vive Gran Canaria App");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Escribe aqui el texto de tu mensaje");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Empresas_SingleItemView.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void openLlamar(View view) 
    {
         try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+telefonoEmpresa));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed", e);
            }
    }
    public void openVotar(View view)
    {
        Log.i("Response", "Hemos entrado en openVotar: ");
        ConnectionTask task = new ConnectionTask();
        String[] params = new String[2];
        String url = "http://XXXXX/cambiarvaloracionempresa.php?id="+idEmpresa;
        params[0] = url;
        //params[1] = somethingelseifneeded;
        task.execute(params);   }
    private class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
             URL aURL;
                /* Will be filled and displayed later. */
                String aString = null;
                try {
        aURL = new URL(
                urls[0]);

        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        final HttpURLConnection aHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();

        /* Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection. */
        InputStream aInputStream = aHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream aBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                aInputStream);

        /* Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1) */
        ByteArrayBuffer aByteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = aBufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            aByteArrayBuffer.append((byte) current);
        }


        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        aString = new String(aByteArrayBuffer.toByteArray());               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            return aString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                   TextView aTextView;Log.i("Response JSON", result);
                   TextView txtvaloracionempresa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valoracionEmpresa);
                txtvaloracionempresa.setText(result);

    // result is what you got from your connection
    //aTextView.setText(result);

        }

    }

}
```

How could I refresh the number of votes on the first activity (list view) when the user goes back to it from the second activity (detail view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter in order to refresh the listview.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() should be called after every change in your datset.
If you are doing it in say a for loop the

```
for (int i = ; ; ){
…
…
adapter.addItem(item);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

otherwise you can call it after the loop.

Also, notifyDataSetChanged() should be called from the UI thread

Check out [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Also, this is a very helpful video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s

Comment: Thank you Fareya, but where should I include the call to notifyDataSetChanged()...